# How can I make btrfs pretend to be ext4?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, btrfs

Dropbox have just announced that their Linux client will only support ext4 in the future. I currently use Dropbox on a btrfs partition (without any issues). Apparently xattr support is essential. Both ext4 and btrfs support this, and indeed I’m not aware of any ext4 feature that btrfs does not also support.

I don’t know how Dropbox intends to detect the filesystem, but is there any way I can get btrfs to pretend to be ext4?

Comment: First thing I would try and would be "mount --bind"

Answer (score 2):

Without modifications to the kernel, probably not. And even then it might not be a good idea, the btrfs tools might refuse to work once they think the file system is not btrfs.

Will Dropbox just not support it as in not answer questions, or will the program actively avoid running on any other file system? If it is the latter, there are many ways to detect a file system, and you wouldn't be able to fool them all.

Comment: Reference https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Syncing-and-uploads/Dropbox-client-warns-me-that-it-ll-stop-syncing-in-Nov-why/m-p/290065/highlight/true#M42255 - DropBox is only going to support _unencrypted_ 4th extended filesystem on Linux as of November of this year.  (LUKS will work, but encryptfs will not)

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to handle this is to create an ext4 loopback image in your Btrfs filesystem, then mount it at some temporary location, move the files you sync with Dropbox into that filesystem, then remount it at the top-level directory where Dropbox syncs.

This will keep Dropbox working, but you don't need to replace your whole filesystem. You will still get some of the benefits of Btrfs, as you could snapshot the loopback image and such.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to create an ext4 file on btrfs, staring in a directory where you want the image stored

```
truncate -s 100G dropbox.img
chown root:root dropbox.img
chmod 600 dropbox.img
mkfs.ext4 -j dropbox.img
mkdir /opt/dropbox
mount -t ext4 -o loop {path}/dropbox.img /opt/dropbox
chmod 777 /opt/dropbox
umount /opt/dropbox
```

Now, edit `/etc/fstab` and add

```
{path}/dropbox.img      /opt/dropbox            ext4    loop            0 0
```

And now if you `mount -a`, you will have a permanent ext4 filesystem on the btrfs

---

I choose `truncate` rather than `fallocate` because the `dropbox.img` file will be "thin provisioned" (a sparse file) on the filesystem rather than normal. What this means is that 100GB will not be used up right away, but rather slowly overtime as dropbox reads and writes over time.

Answer (score 0):

### Dropbox has brought back support for ZFS, XFS, Btrfs and eCryptFS

Dropbox has brought back support for ZFS, XFS, Btrfs and **eCryptFS** on Linux. A Dropbox [client update](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Desktop-client-builds/Beta-Build-77-3-127/td-p/354660) brings back support for ZFS and XFS on 64-bit Linux systems, and eCryptFS and Btrfs on all Linux systems.

Links:

- [Dropbox Brings Back Support For ZFS, XFS, Btrfs And eCryptFS On Linux](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/07/dropbox-brings-back-support-for-zfs-xfs.html)
- [Maestral](https://github.com/SamSchott/maestral-dropbox) lightweight open source Dropbox client for Linux

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, it is possible

And without needing kernel modifications as suggested by another answer. This is the solution I used when I had a root file system with ext3 that Dropbox did not like. The way Dropbox detects what file system is being used is via the /etc/mtab file. That file keeps track of the currently mounted file systems, but is largely a legacy from other UNIX systems. Certain modifications can be made safely without breaking things. In this case, changing the type of the file system that it reports. The contents is a convenience for user space programs like Dropbox, but is not required by the kernel for proper operation.

First of all, make sure that /etc/mtab is a plain text file. On many modern Linux systems, it is a symbolic link to /proc/self/mounts that can't be modified. If that is the case, replace the link with a copy of that file:

```
rm /etc/mtab
cp /proc/self/mounts /etc/mtab
```

After that, you can modify the file to change the file type, as found in the third column, to ext4 so Dropbox believes it so.

```
sed 's/\<btrfs\>/ext4/' /etc/mtab
```

Now, you should be able to start Dropbox without complaint. This process will have to be repeated for each boot so I put it     sed 's/<btrfs>/ext4/' /etc/mtab
all into a script that I run after I log in.

```
cat <<EOF >fix-mtab.sh
#!/bin/sh

sudo rm /etc/mtab
sudo cp /proc/self/mounts /etc/mtab
sudo sed 's/\<btrfs\>/ext4/' /etc/mtab
EOF
chmod +x fix-mtab.sh
./fix-mtab.sh
```